# how to send message digest alongwith the actual message over the network

Tags: language-agnostic, network-programming

Let `E=encrypt(msg)` `D=digest(E)`

If I send E+D to the peer. How is the peer supposed to know that it needs to split the incoming message at E and calculate its digest and verify against D.

Should the final msg contain some kind of length parameter or a delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic mechanism to add signatures independent of protocol. Each network protocol that allows for digital signatures, or digests, or encryption, does so differently.

For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security

Comment: Completely ignoring the standard protocols for encryption and hashing, I was wondering how (in terms of raw messages) the hash is sent. Upon asking someone else, I learnt that the hash is sent separately and the message separately. Is this correct?

Comment: The answer is 'it depends'. One protocol might send it glued to the front, another glued to the back, and a third may stick it in a header off somewhere.

Comment: And then use a delimiter/length to denote the message?

Comment: If the signature is fixed length, you don't need that if it's first. If the message is self-describing in length .... well, that's your case.